# Show that all real numbers are expressible as an infinite product of rational numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series

Intuitively, this fact seems true, but I don't have the tools to verify (let alone prove) it myself. I'd appreciate any ideas you have ^^

edit:@skyking very little unfortunately.  I've yet to start a higher pure maths course, but I have a tendancy to ask demanding questions of myself and then be compelled to answer them

another edit:I have learned about limits (to the extent of being able to define calculus operators on R from first principles); just couldn't figure out how to apply it to this problem

Comment: Hint: Write $x$ as a limit of a sequence $(x_n)$ of non-zero rational numbers, and use $x_{n+1}/x_n$ as factors.

Comment: Do you realize that it's very similar to the fact that all real numbers are expressible as a limit of rational numbers? What prior knowledge do you have?

Comment: Let $x$ bea  real number and $q_n$ be a sequence of rationals converging to $x$. Then $$x = q_1 \cdot \frac{q_2}{q_1} \cdot \frac{q_3}{q_2} \cdot \frac{q_4}{q_3} \cdots $$

Comment: I was unaware that the intersection of the collection of people able to make sense of infinite products and of the collection of people unable to solve the present question was not empty.

Comment: @Did There are people who play with infinite series before learning the formal definition of limits.  For example, back in school, I wrote a program to calculate $\pi$ using an infinite series even though I had not yet learned $\epsilon, \delta$ and all that stuff.

Comment: @badjohn Then describing the very off-balanced background of the OP seems a requisite to even make sense of the question, don't you think?

Comment: @Did Yes.  It is common for people to start playing with infinite sums before realising the need to have a formal definition of what they are.  Some, such as the OP, ask fairly sensible questions while others ask crazy ones.  I remember that much of my first year at university was repeating what I had learned in school but more formally.  I mentioned calculating $\pi$ in school.  I had seen the $\tan^{-1}$ series but realised that it would converge too slowly to be useful.  I calculated the Taylor series for $\sin^{-1}$  and used that.  I did not yet know the formal definitions of limits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the question was sum rather than product, could you do it?

E.g. $\pi = 3 + .1 + .04 + .001 + . 0005 + . . .$

For a product, try the same approximations.

$\pi = 3 \times \frac{3.1}{3} \times \frac{3.14}{3.1} \times \frac{3.141}{3.14} ...$

Comment: Very nice, +1 $ $

Comment: It's the same idea as the comments above.  No plagiarism, I was typing at the same time as them.

Comment: With reference to your edit: if you have not yet studied infinite series and the definition of limits then neither the sum nor the product is formally defined.  You will just have to rely on them intuitively giving the correct results.  However, if one does then the other will since if you truncate both of my examples at the same point then you get the same value.

Comment: Apologies for the late "Solved" tick.  Thank you very much for such a concise and insightful answer